# sscanf returning 1 reading a string

Tags: c

What does it mean when it is returning one?

And can anyone help me out to find where my problem is?

```
char* line = "\"ThisId\":\"\"";
char key[32], value[512];
if (sscanf(line, "\"%31[^\"]\":\"%511[^\"]\"", key, value) != 2) {
    return false;
}
```

I want to read key = ThisId

and

value should be empty in this case.

It look like key is getting the whole string and therefor value is not gonna get any.

Comment: Read The Manual! It means only one element got read/converted.

Comment: Did you forget to put `[^\"]` between `%31` and `\"`?

Comment: @IanAbbott sorry, forgot to put it in the example - but it is not working.. still returning 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that format specifier `[...]` does not match an empty input. Confer, for example, the meaning of [conversion specifiers](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2p12) in the linked C standard draft, and note the "nonempty" (emphasis are mine):

> [ ... Matches a **nonempty sequence of characters** from a set of expected characters (the scanset).

So an "empty" value, i.e. an input without any character between the two `\"`, will simply not match the format, and that's why the result of `scanf` is not `2` in such a case .

Anyway, `scanf` with several input formats and characters in between usually becomes very tricky and error prone. I'd suggest to read in a complete line, e.g. using `fgets`, and then parse it, e.g. using `strtok`, or `strchr`. As you already have a line at hand, you will - of course - skip the `fgets`-thing.

Comment: even if I change to this, it still happens..
It looks like "key" is getting the whole string. char* line = "\"ThisId\":\"aaa\""

Comment: @Noob14 If you know what's good for you, you'll want to keep those scansets *separate* for this precise reason. The `%[`scanset`]` operates act subtly unlike most other format specifiers. Read this answer *very carefully*; it explains the phenomena... then realise that your *only* solution is to *separate the scansets*...

Comment: @Noob14 For example, have you considered that your `sscanf` returns `0` when the *first* field is the empty one?

Comment: Stephan, please consider using links to [the POSIX manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fscanf.html) in the future, as the cppreference page you've linked to is missing quite a bit of information... alternatively, you can see it [references](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#References) the [C standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2). Unlike cppreference, the POSIX standard fairly closely reflects the C standard, given that C is the Unix system language that would make sense...

Comment: @autistic: thanks, adapted the answer and linked a c standard draft.

Answer (score 2):

> where my problem is?

Incorrect expectation of what `sscanf()` does when a specifier fails to match anything.

---

```
char* line = "\"ThisId\":\"\"";
char key[32], value[512];
if (sscanf(line, "\"%31[^\"]\":\"%511[^\"]\"", key, value) != 2) {
```

Since `line` had nothing to match `"%511[^\"]"`, the scanning stopped.  `value[]` is unchanged and `scanf()` reports the number of specifiers successfully scanned  `1` in this case.

---

Another problem exits.

With `line2` below, the `sscanf()` would populate `value[]` with `"xyz"` and `sscanf()` return 2 as expected.

```
char* line2 = "\"ThisId\":\"xyz\"";
```

With `line3` below, the `sscanf()` would populate `value[]` with `"xyz"` and `sscanf()` return 2 even though `line3` does not have a final `'\"'`.

```
char* line3 = "\"ThisId\":\"xyz";
```

With `line4` below, the `sscanf()` would populate `value[]` with `"xyz"` and `sscanf()` return 2 even though `line4` contians extra junk after the final `'\"'`.

```
char* line4 = "\"ThisId\":\"xyz\"blah";
```

---

OP's goal is match either 1 of 2 different `sscanf` formats.  I find using string literal concatenation makes code easier to understand and maintain.

```
#define KEY_FMT "\"%31[^\"]\"
#define SEP_FMT ":"
#define VAL_FMT "\"%511[^\"]\"
#define EMPTY_FMT "\"\"

KEY_FMT SEP_FMT VAL_FMT      /* key and value */
KEY_FMT SEP_FMT EMPTY_FMT    /* key and empty value */
```

A simple solution is to scan the string twice and test if scanning reached the end.  Code can test that with a final `"%n"` to record the numbers of characters scanned so far *if scanning reached that point*.

```
#define N_FMT "%n"

int n = 0;
sscanf(line, KEY_FMT SEP_FMT VAL_FMT N_FMT, key, value, &n);
if (n > 0 && line[n] == '\0') {
  return true; // Found key and value
}

n = 0;
sscanf(line, KEY_FMT SEP_FMT EMPTY_FMT N_FMT, key, &n);
if (n > 0 && line[n] == '\0') {
  value[0] = '\0';
  return true; // Found key and empty value
}

return false;
```

A useful variation is to scan in parts

```
int n = 0;
sscanf(line, KEY_FMT SEP_FMT N_FMT, key, &n);
if (n == 0) {
  return false; // Key or separator not found
}
line += n; // advance

n = 0;
sscanf(line, VALUE_FMT N_FMT, &n);
if (n > 0 && line[n] == '\0') {
  return true; // Found value
}

n = 0;
sscanf(line, EMPTY_FMT N_FMT, value, &n);
if (n > 0 && line[n] == '\0') {
  value[0] = '\0'; 
  return true; // Found empty value
}

return false;
```

Lastly, consider allowing whitespace in various parts of the scan.

```
#define KEY_FMT " \"%31[^\"]\"
#define SEP_FMT " :"
#define VAL_FMT " \"%511[^\"]\"
#define EMPTY_FMT " \"\"  
#define N_FMT " %n"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because `[^\"]` will read the characters till it reaches `\"`. Since your input  `"\"ThisId\":\"\"";` does not contain any extra character for second string.
 `sscanf` is not reading anything for `value`.

If you are intended to read empty value put `' '` in the input as below

```
char* line = "\"ThisId\":\" \"";
```